# Python tools for cross-wavelet transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, wavelet

I want to compute the cross wavelet transform/coherence. I just learnt `pycwt` is buggy as it is unable to reconstruct the original signal. The `pywavelets` tools appears to only have capabilities for the direct transform and not the cross transform. Are there any other tools I am missing that compute the cross-wavelet transform? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this help [Continuous wavelet transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html)?

Comment: No, that is not for cross-wavelet transforms.

Comment: [This](https://duducosmos.github.io/PIWavelet/) package acts as a Python interface over Matlab for using the famous [Grinsted et al (2004)](http://noc.ac.uk/using-science/crosswavelet-wavelet-coherence) software. I haven't found anything else in Python. I had to change to [WaveletComp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WaveletComp/index.html) (R) -easy and simple to use